# Mysql Union in PHP not returning correct results

Tags: php, mysql, union

I currently have a mysql Union query that works when placed directly into mysql via the command line, PHP MyAdmin or run in a Mysql editor like Mysql Workbench.  When I run the query through my PHP class it returns two duplicate rows.

The Query:

```
SELECT `n`.`draftrd`, `n`.`draftteam`, `n`.`nflteam`, `nt`.`logo`, 
    `nt`.`name`, `nt`.`nflcity`,
    `p`.`class`, `p`.`first_name`, `p`.`last_name`
FROM `players` as `p` 
LEFT JOIN `nfl` as `n` ON `p`.`playerid` = `n`.`playerid`
LEFT JOIN `nflteams` as `nt` ON `n`.`nflteam` = `nt`.`nflid` 
WHERE `n`.`playerid` = 2007000001
UNION
SELECT `n`.`draftrd` as `draftRd`, `n`.`draftteam` as `draftTm`, `n`.`nflteam`, 
    `nt`.`logo`, 
    `nt`.`name` as `draftName`, `nt`.`nflcity` as `draftCity`, `p`.`class`, 
    `p`.`first_name`, `p`.`last_name`
FROM `players` as `p` 
LEFT JOIN `nfl` as `n` ON `p`.`playerid` = `n`.`playerid`
LEFT JOIN `nflteams` as `nt` ON `n`.`draftteam` = `nt`.`nflid` 
WHERE `n`.`playerid` = 2007000001
```

In the editor it returns:

```
+---------+-----------+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------+------------+-----------+---------+
| draftrd | draftteam | nflteam | logo        | name    | nflcity  | class | first_name | last_name | tableid |
+---------+-----------+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------+------------+-----------+---------+
| 2       | 2         | 12      | giants.png  | Giants  | New York | 2007  | Martellus  | Bennett   |       1 |
| 2       | 2         | 12      | cowboys.png | Cowboys | Dallas   | 2007  | Martellus  | Bennett   |       1 |
+---------+-----------+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-------+------------+-----------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The PHP return is:
(The var_dump version)

```
array(18) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["draftrd"]=> string(1) "2" 
    [1]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["draftteam"]=> string(1) "2"
    [2]=> string(2) "12" 
    ["nflteam"]=> string(2) "12" 
    [3]=> string(10) "giants.png" 
    ["logo"]=> string(10) "giants.png" 
    [4]=> string(6) "Giants" 
    ["name"]=> string(6) "Giants" 
    [5]=> string(8) "New York" 
    ["nflcity"]=> string(8) "New York" 
    [6]=> string(4) "2007" 
    ["class"]=> string(4) "2007"
    [7]=> string(9) "Martellus"
    ["first_name"]=> string(9) "Martellus"
    [8]=> string(7) "Bennett" 
    ["last_name"]=> string(7) "Bennett" 
}
```

I'm not sure what the issue is and why it's not working properly.  I tried creating a temporary table and storing the query in it but it still gives me the duplicated rows.  Is there an easier way to do this or an explanation of why it's happening?  I've dumped the query in PHP to see if the issue is with it's construction but the dumped query returns the rows I'm looking for when run on the command line.

Comment: Please try formatting that again...

Comment: Yeah, it was definitely ugly on the first run. Haha

Comment: I don't understand to what you refer with "it is duplicated", if you mean that you have [3]=> string(10) "giants.png" and ["logo"]=> string(10) "giants.png" this is because you can access the query results either with a numered index (ex. result[3]) or with a text index (ex. result["logo"])

Comment: What did you do the `var_dump()` on?  Also, are you using the same SQL query for both?  I noticed the manual example includes a `tableid` but the PHP one doesn't.

Comment: Those tableid columns were added to try and troubleshoot the issue with a fellow developer.  They aren't being used in the actual PHP class.  I removed them to prevent further confusion.

Comment: @Rafael It's producing two identical rows with all values the same when it should have 2 rows with slightly different information included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL handles in PHP allow you to iterate through the result array in different ways. For example, you can choose to iterate through an associative array by key (e.g.: `echo $result['draftteam'];`), or you can iterate by index through a normal array (e.g.: `echo $result[2];`).

When you use the `fetch_array()` command, you are, by default, fetching both types at the same time. This would produce the arary that you provided.

If you are trying to create a dynamic table based off of the query (i.e.: one that writes each column name in a `<th>` before emptying it's contents into the `<td>`s below), then you should use the `fetch_assoc()` command, rather than the `fetch_array()` command. This will only return the text keys in your array.

```
while($arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        echo $key .' => '. $value .'<br />'."\n";
    }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Thanks for this.  It clears up a few misconceptions I had about the return array.  I knew there were both types but didn't realize it returns both for each query unless specified. While it didn't exactly answer my question it did lead me to it.  I have a function returning mysql_fetch_array instead of the mysql_query so it was only returning the first result.  I return the query and it gives me all the information I'm looking for.  I'll have to look into the best way to return this information as I'm sure returning mysql_query can't be the best option.